# Nielsen & Chuang, 10th anniversary edition, page 85, equation 2.92

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

I don't understand why the stated equation is not equal to the expectation value of $m^2$
[image: calculation]

Comment: Are the matrices $M$ promised to have eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, that is specified in the text.

Comment: Are you sure? It's not in my older version of the book (and shouldn't be)

Comment: Hopefully that explains my misunderstanding. Here is the text: Postulate 3: Quantum measurements are described by a collection {Mm} of
measurement operators. These are operators acting on the state space of the
system being measured. The index m refers to the measurement outcomes that
may occur in the experiment. If the state of the quantum system is |ψ
immediately before the measurement then the probability that result m occurs is given by ... and the equation follows

Comment: I see that in the following text, they do a simple example where M^2=M, but that does not answer my question

Comment: please see https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation for how to format math on the site

Comment: It equals the expected value of $M^\dagger M$. That's the same as $M^2$ if and only if $M$ is Hermitian. "Having eigenvalues" is not the same as being Hermitian. Although the equation you posted seems to assume $M$ has a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors. That still leaves the possibility of $M$ being normal but not Hermitian. For example a matrix like $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&i\end{pmatrix}$. If you also assume $m_i$ to be real, then yes $M$ is Hermitian and that expression is just another way to write the expectation value of $M^2$

Comment: I don't think Hermitian means the same as idempotent

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have changed *a collection of operators* $\{M_m\}$ into a single operator $M=\sum_mmM_m$ (this is actually an *observable*).

The whole point of the *collection* is that you handle each of the cases $m$ separately - you do a measurement and your measurement apparatus gives you one value $m$ (corresponding to a specific $M_m$) and you calculate the consequences of that.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that sum from. I didn't sum anything. Neither does (2.92). Rather, I am treating the "collection of operators" as a collection with a single element. In that case, (2.92) appears to be in error.

Comment: The sum is what I've had to introduce to recreate your calculation in the notation of N&C. Note that if you *think* you're doing the calculation with a single operator, that single operator is something that has to square to identity because it must satisfy the completeness relation. Then all the $m_i^2=1$.

Comment: Take a look at Box 2.5 on page 91. About halfway down you see the statement PiPj=dijPi. So, as you said, they really are assuming that m^2=I. But nowhere in the text (that I can see prior to section 2.2.3) do they mention this important restriction. That's pretty messed up.

Comment: It's stated in equation 2.94 as part of the postulate.